# What is the current size of the node in rolling mode?

Tags: node

According to documentation this mode is

> Only requires a minimal and bounded disk storage.

But what is the exact size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit complicated to answer precisely to that question. Indeed, it mainly depend on the network and its "traffic". In addition to that, it is likely to increase slightly as the chain's ledger is enriched.

If we consider the today's `mainnet` case with ~650k blocks and using the irmin2 storage backend, it is around 300Mb when freshly imported from a rolling snapshot. The maximum storage size (before cleaning the last cycle) is around 600Mb, assuming manual garbage collection of the context as it is not automatic yet.
A few gigabytes of storage should be plenty enough to run a rolling node.